# PDF generation on Python 3.2

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.x, pdf-generation

I'm trying to make a PDF file in Python, but all of the tools I find only work on Python 2.7 (or lower) and I'm using 3.2. I there a tool or something that works on 3.2 and generates PDF files? Or a way to make 2.7 (or lower) code work on 3.2?

Answer (score 1):

Not personally tested with Python 3.x, but official page says [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/) works with it. It allows for HTML to PDF conversion, so depending on your needs and the rest of the project this may be an advantage or disadvantage.

For a low-level "draw the PDF yourself" you might want to try [cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/), but looks like the automatic installation is a bit incomplete: [Cairo example works with Python 2.7 but does not work in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372909/cairo-in-python-3)

To convert python 2.x code to python 3.x code you may use the following two tools:

1. [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)
2. Your brain

The latter tool are much more powerful, and sort of guarantees successful conversion, but a little bit slow compared to the former.